# asyncio aiohttp cancel an http request polling, return a result

Tags: python, setinterval, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm using this code to create an http request every 5 seconds.

```
async def do_request():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('http://localhost:8000/') as resp:
            print(resp.status)
            return await resp.text()
```

Didn't find a bulit-in scheduler, so I wrote this function (similar to javascript):

```
async def set_interval(fn, seconds):
    while True:
        await fn()
        await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
```

And this is how I use it:

```
asyncio.ensure_future(set_interval(do_request, 5))
```

The code works fine, but I have two requirements:
1. How can I stop the set_interval after it is added to the event loop? (similar to javascript `clearInterval()`)
2. Is it possible that set_interval will return the value of the function that it is wrapping? In this example I will want the response text. Other pattern that will do the same task will be accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Canceling the job

> 1. How can I stop the set_interval after it is added to the event loop? (similar to javascript `clearInterval()`)

One option is to cancel the returned task:

```
# create_task is like ensure_future, but guarantees to return a task
task = loop.create_task(set_interval(do_request, 5))
...
task.cancel()
```

This will also cancel whatever future `set_interval` was awaiting. If you don't want that, and want `fn()` to continue in the background instead, use `await asyncio.shield(fn())` instead.

### Distributing values generated by the function

> 2. Is it possible that `set_interval` will return the value of the function that it is wrapping? In this example I will want the response text. Other pattern that will do the same task will be accepted.

Since `set_interval` is running in an infinite loop, it cannot return anything - a return would terminate the loop.

### Exposing values via async iteration

If you need the values from the function, one option is to redesign `set_interval` as a generator. The caller would obtain the values using `async for`, which is quite readable, but also very different from JavaScript's `setInterval`:

```
async def iter_interval(fn, seconds):
    while True:
        yield await fn()
        await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
```

Usage example:

```
async def x():
    print('x')
    return time.time()

async def main():
    async for obj in iter_interval(x, 1):
        print('got', obj)

# or asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
asyncio.run(main())
```

### Broadcasting values via a future

Another approach is for each pass of the loop to broadcast the generated value to a global future which other coroutines can await; something along the lines of:

```
next_value = None

async def set_interval(fn, seconds):
    global next_value
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        next_value = loop.create_task(fn())
        await next_value
        await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
```

With usage like this:

```
# def x() as above

async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(set_interval(x, 1))
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        obj = await next_value
        print('got', obj)
```

The above simple implementation has a major issue, though: Once the next value is provided, `next_value` is not immediately replaced by a new `Future`, but only after the sleep. This means that `main()` prints "got " in a tight loop, until a new timestamp arrives. It also means removing `await asyncio.sleep(0)` would actually break it, because the only `await` in the loop would never suspend and `set_interval` would no longer get a chance to run.

This is clearly not intended. We would like the loop in `main()` to *wait* for the next value, even after an initial value is obtained. To do so, `set_interval` must be a bit smarter:

```
next_value = None

async def set_interval(fn, seconds):
    global next_value
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    next_value = loop.create_task(fn())
    await next_value

    async def iteration_pass():
        await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
        return await fn()

    while True:
        next_value = loop.create_task(iteration_pass())
        await next_value
```

This version ensures that the `next_value` is assigned to as soon as the previous one has been awaited. To do so, it uses a helper `iteration_pass` coroutine which serves as a convenient task to put into `next_value` before `fn()` is actually ready to run. With that in place, `main()` can look like this:

```
async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(set_interval(x, 1))
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    while True:
        obj = await next_value
        print('got', obj)
```

`main()` is no longer busy-looping and has the expected output of exactly one timestamp per second. However, we still need the *initial* `asyncio.sleep(0)` because `next_value` is simply not available when we just call `create_task(set_interval(...))`. This is because a task scheduled with `create_task` is only run after returning to the event loop. Omitting the `sleep(0)` would result in an error along the lines of "objects of type `NoneType` cannot be awaited".

To resolve this, `set_interval` can be split into a regular `def` which schedules the initial loop iteration and immediately initializes `next_value`. The function instantiates and immediately returns a coroutine object that does the rest of the work.

```
next_value = None

def set_interval(fn, seconds):
    global next_value
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    next_value = loop.create_task(fn())

    async def iteration_pass():
        await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
        return await fn()

    async def interval_loop():
        global next_value
        while True:
            next_value = loop.create_task(iteration_pass())
            await next_value

    return interval_loop()
```

Now `main()` can be written in the obvious way:

```
async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(set_interval(x, 1))
    while True:
        obj = await next_value
        print('got', obj)
```

Compared to async iteration, the advantage of this approach is that multiple listeners can observe the values.

Comment: Thanks! Using this `async for`, I will also have an infinite for loop, correct (But I think that shouldn't be a problem because it is a non blocking loop)? Second, it would be really helpful to see code of usage of a global future like you've explained.

Comment: @user3599803 In case of a generator, the loop is in both the caller and the generator, with a value being transmitted at each iteration. And yes, waiting for the new iteration (as well as generating a new value) are both async and therefore do not block the event loop.

Comment: @user3599803 I've added that code to the answer, at the cost of additional verbiage. Correctly broadcasting the values out of a coroutine is somewhat of an advanced topic.